# Setting maxDate in primeng-calendar range selection dynamically

Tags: primeng, primeng-calendar

I am trying to set the maxDate in a range selection dynamically based on the selected start date.
But the calendar just closes after the start date selection since it has to reset the maxDate.

Here is the link for the sample.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-8vt4f7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm having this issue also, did you find a resolution?